# Unknown inability to access elements of array

Tags: php

I am reading in a .ini file containing database connection information.
However, when I try to access the info, I am receiving undefined offset and undefined index errors whenever I try to access it.  Code as follows:

```
$connectInfo = parse_ini_file('/configuration.ini');
echo $connectInfo['hostname'];
echo $connectInfo[0];
echo $connectInfo[0]['hostname'];
echo $connectInfo[0][0];
var_dump($connectInfo);

$connectInfo = parse_ini_file('/configuration.ini', TRUE);
echo $connectInfo['hostname'];
echo $connectInfo[0];
echo $connectInfo[0]['hostname'];
echo $connectInfo[0][0];
var_dump($connectInfo);
```

Yet, when I do a vardump, I get following output:

```
array (size=6)
  ''hostname'' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  ''database'' => string 'nestedtree' (length=10)
  ''username'' => string 'root' (length=4)
  ''password'' => string '' (length=0)
  ''port'' => string '3306' (length=4)
  ''socket'' => string '' (length=0)
```

and

```
array (size=1)
  'connection' => 
    array (size=6)
      ''hostname'' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
      ''database'' => string 'nestedtree' (length=10)
      ''username'' => string 'root' (length=4)
      ''password'' => string '' (length=0)
      ''port'' => string '3306' (length=4)
  ''socket'' => string '' (length=0)
```

Any help identifying what this issue is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use quotes in your .ini file for the section headers?

Answer (score 0):

The array you're trying to access is a sub-array of the 'connection' array.  Try accessing it like this:

```
echo $connectInfo['connection']['hostname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear it was issue with code.  Appears to be issue with Wamp server.  Using same code on Apache server, code worked just fine.
Thanks to all who answered.